# Problem updating the html-design.html file in tridion

Tags: 2013-sp1, dxa

I was trying hard to [Deploy fonts using DXA](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11882/how-to-deploy-fonts-using-dxa) and after two days of trial and error, I found a strange behavior in tridion.

There is a multimedia component with name **HTML Design**. This component has an attachment **html-design.zip**. I downloaded this file of around 4.5 MB and then unzipped it and did some modifications. Zipped again and replaced the original attachment with new one (of about 9 MB).

I saved and closed the multimedia component. Opened the component again. Now when I click 'Save to Disk' button, old file of 4.5 MB is downloaded instead of 9MB file. 
But instead of 'Save to Disk' button, if I double click on attachment icon, the 9MB file is downloaded.

This does not looks like a caching issue as 2 different behaviors can be seen.

After publishing, I am getting the old file contents (the contents of 4.5 MB) file in the BinaryData folder and not getting any modifications I did.

This may be the cause of [Deploy fonts using DXA](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11882/how-to-deploy-fonts-using-dxa)?

**Update:**

Today I am trying with another file and same issue. I even renamed the file, uploaded to tridion and when I save to disk again, I get an old file. Check the screenshot.[image]

Comment: Are you using 2013 SP1 HR1, or just 2013 SP1? Also in what browser are you seeing this behavior?

Comment: 2013 SP1 HR1 , Browser - firefox

Answer (score 2):

From your first part of the description, it sounds more like a UI issue, although a strange one. When you mention that a pubish also doesn't change your data, that would indicate a deeper problem.

I haven't seen this behavior before on my 2013 SP1 HR1 test systems (nor on 2013 SP1 btw, but didn't test the exact scenario there, although I did do a lot of changes to the `html-design.zip` while developing). So I'm wondering if you are not being hit by several caching issues along the way?

After updating the HTML design, assuming you also updated the version number in the `HTML Design Configuration` Component before publishing it, then your website will not be affected by a browser cache issue.
If you also called `/admin/refresh` after publish, your web application will have also been refreshed.

But I have to say, most of these type of issues I have encountered were always related to the most common Tridion issue, the Component was not correctly checked in before publish...

> ps. not sure if it is directly related to your other issue, because I understood that your also didn't get the fonts in the `dist` folder when you build the HTML design outside of Tridion already.

### update

If you have the HTML design work for you when you build it locally, and you didn't need to make any changes to the `package.json` or `Gruntfile.js`, then it should also work at publish time. You could try a local build with the `package.json` and `Gruntfile.js` from the `build-files.zip` (also need to add its `bower.json` I think, the rest of the files from the zip will be downloaded when you build).

Comment: No, I do get the fonts in the dist folder now. I did fresh build after placing fonts in asset folder. so now the problem is fonts folder is created in dist folder. But not getting published. I also updated version number. Everything else is getting published successfully from tridion. Will try again.

Comment: okay then it sounds like you indeed have some issues getting the correct changes published out... Not sure if this is something which easily can be solved through a place like this btw.

Comment: The issue did not reoccur after restarting tridion services on CMS server. But this was really a weird issue. Monitoring for some time now...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may be using Chrome as your browser. It's an infamous issue. Try the same thing in Firefox and that should sort you.

Comment: on a contrary , I am using firefox :)